# adding 2 variables to a single array position

Tags: php

I am trying to add 2 variables which both happen to be checkboxes to an array that is part of a backend called SPIP.

The current array setup for the single checkbox looks like this:

```
$UpcomingEvent = 'is_upcoming_event';
$ThermometerEvent = 'is_thermometer_event';
$GLOBALS['champs_extra'] = array (
    'articles' => array (
        $nis => "checkbox|propre|New Inspirational Stories?",
        $UpcomingEvent => "checkbox|propre|Is a Upcoming Event? (<em>present into Home page?</em>)",
        $ThermometerEvent => "checkbox|propre|Add thermometer to event?",
        'redirect_to_hyperlink' => "checkbox|propre|Redirect article to Hyperlink?"
    )
);

$GLOBALS['champs_extra_proposes'] = Array (
    'articles' => Array (
        // tous : par defaut aucun champs extra sur les articles
        'tous' => 'redirect_to_hyperlink',
        // seul le champs extra "new_inspirational_stories" est propos� dans le secteur 42)
        /**
         * UpComming Events
         */
        '44' => $UpcomingEvent,
        '45' => $UpcomingEvent,
)
    );
```

I want to add the ThermometerEvent variable to the array position 44 and 45 as well but can't figure out how to do it without overwriting the 44 or 45 position.

I tried putting it in another array like so but it did not work:

```
'45' => array($UpcomingEvent, $ThermometerEvent),
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What "did not work"? Your `'45' => array` looks to be fine. How were you attempting to access those values aftewards?

If you were to do

```
echo $GLOBALS['champs_extra_proposes']['articles']['44'];
```

you'd just get "Array", but doing

```
echo $GLOBALS['champs_extra_proposes']['articles']['44'][0];
```

should get you the value of `$UpcomingEvent`

Comment: ah makes sense. I was getting "Array" I'll have to dig deeper. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could have a fully two-dimensional array - see here:

http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/multidimensional_arrays.php

Or use lists: http://php.net/list

```
<?php

$info = array('coffee', 'brown', 'caffeine');

// Listing all the variables
list($drink, $color, $power) = $info;
echo "$drink is $color and $power makes it special.\n";

// Listing some of them
list($drink, , $power) = $info;
echo "$drink has $power.\n";

// Or let's skip to only the third one
list( , , $power) = $info;
echo "I need $power!\n";

// list() doesn't work with strings
list($bar) = "abcde";
var_dump($bar); // NULL
?>
```